# Converting Julian Date (5 or 4 character) to Gregorian and vice versa

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, calculated-columns, vba

I'm trying to create a VBA script or a formula/function that converts a Julian Date (5001 or 15001) to a regular date (01/01/2015).  I was able to find the following formula that converts a 5 character Julian Date to Gregorian Date and it works fine.  I'm no mathematician so I'm not sure how to write the formula for the 4 character JD and I have no idea where to even start for the reverse (Regular Date to JD).  Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

The formula for the 5 character JD is here:

```
Assuming that the Julian Date is in A1:


=DATE(IF(0+(LEFT(A1,2))<30,2000,1900)+LEFT(A1,2),1,RIGHT(A1,3))
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test the length of the target cell to determine whether or not it is 4 or 5 characters long (line break for clarity):

```
=DATE(IF(0+(VALUE(IF(LEN(A1)=5,LEFT(A1,2),LEFT(A1,1))))<30,2000,1900)
      +VALUE(IF(LEN(A1)=5,LEFT(A1,2),LEFT(A1,1))),1,RIGHT(A1,3))
```

The reverse is much easier - just build a number out of the date parts and cast the resulting string to a number to get rid of any leading zero:

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(YEAR(A1),2)&TEXT(A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0),"000"))
```

**EDIT:** Per comments, the following method will use the present decade if the first digit of a 4 year Julian date is less than or equal to the last digit of the current year, otherwise use 200x:

```
=DATE(IF(0+(VALUE(IF(LEN(A1)=5,LEFT(A1,2),LEFT(A1,1))))<30,
      IF(LEN(A1)=5,2000,IF(LEFT(A1,1)<=RIGHT(YEAR(NOW()),1),2010, 2000)),1900)
      +VALUE(IF(LEN(A1)=5,LEFT(A1,2),LEFT(A1,1))),1,RIGHT(A1,3))
```

Almost forgot... If you need the formula to remain valid after 2019 you can replace the 2010 with `2000+(MID(YEAR(NOW()),3,1)*10)`.

Comment: thanks for the response.  THe formula you provided for JD to Gregorian based on 4 or 5 almost works; however, it has errors.  For instance if the JD is 4 character and is as follows:

'4001' , then that should be 01/01/2014, yet if it is '9001'  then it has to be 01/01/2009.  So it has to be a day that has passed, yet the most recent year.  So if it begins with 5, then 2015, but 6 would be 2006.  Does that make sense?  I can't figure out the conversion.  It's killing me.

Comment: @flwr_pwr - I thought the standard convention for a 4 digit JD was that it had an implicit leading zero.  If 4001 was 1/1/14, there would be no way to distinguish it from 1/1/04, 1/1/24, etc.

Comment: that's accurate in some some systems, so you're definitely not wrong!  But the system that we work with follows the standards that I just mentioned.  I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that originally.  It does make things more complex!

Comment: @flwr_pwr - OK, so that I understand this correctly - if the first digit is less than or equal to the last digit of the current year, then it's in the present decade? Doesn't this invalidate all of your data every year?

Comment: That's accurate and that's accurate.  For the system that facilitates the 4 char JD, the voucher file only has to last 10 years so those records will be historically archived in a legacy system which will then convert to a regular 5 char JD.  I hope I articulated that well enough.  Please let me know.

Comment: That works beautifully! Thank you so much!  It will take me a  while to figure out exactly how it works (so that I can recreate it from scratch if I ever have to) but I love it.  Thanks again!

Comment: @flwr_pwr - Easiest way to do that is to put it in Notepad, break it into its functional parts, and indent it like you would code.  ;-)

Comment: thanks for the tip!  I'll definitely do that.  Thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula from [this](http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/convert-julian-dates-regular-dates-excel-9016.html) page:

```
=DATE(IF(0+(LEFT(JULIAN_DATE_CELL,2))<30,2000,1900)+LEFT(JULIAN_DATE_CELL,2),1,RIGHT(JULIAN_DATE_CELL,3))
```

You need to replace JULIAN_DATE_CELL with the cell number that you stored the Julian date.

Comment: thank you for the response; however, that is the formula I found for the 5 character date (listed in the post).  I'm struggling to calculate for a 4 character Julian date and also vice versa (Gregorian to JD)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to accommodate dates before 2000? If not then you can use this formula:

`=DATE(IF(LEN(A1)=5,LEFT(A1,2)+100,LOOKUP(YEAR(NOW()),FLOOR(YEAR(NOW()),10)+LEFT(A1)-{10,0})),1,RIGHT(A1,3))`

That uses `LOOKUP` function to lookup the current year against the possible options, e.g. currently if you have 6001 in A1 that looks up 2015 against an array like `{2006,2016}` and the lower value is chosen. If you do the same calculation next year `2016` will be chosen.

This formula will work in to the future, e.g. in 2020 it will interpret 9001 as 1st Jan 2019.

For reversing the calculation do you always want a 4 digit JD, what about 2010 or 2020?